# Chef: had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 400 "Bad Request"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to download file from AWS s3 bucket using chef (aws cookbook available in chef supermarket). I keep receiving following error message.

```
Net::HTTPServerException
    ------------------------
    remote_file[/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/s3_file.rb line 36) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 400 "Bad Request"
```

For authentication purpose I am using IAM role. I can download same file using aws s3 command line. This means there is no problem with role itself.

Detail log is given below.

```
Net::HTTPServerException
    ------------------------
    remote_file[/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/s3_file.rb line 36) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 400 "Bad Request"

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/appservers/recipes/appconfig.rb

      3: aws_s3_file "/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret" do
      4:   bucket "app-chefconfig"
      5:   remote_path "encrypted_data_bag_secret"
      6: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/appservers/recipes/appconfig.rb:3:in `from_file'

    aws_s3_file("/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret") do
      action :create
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      path "/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret"
      declared_type :aws_s3_file
      cookbook_name "appservers"
      recipe_name "appconfig"
      bucket "app-chefconfig"
      remote_path "encrypted_data_bag_secret"
      use_etag true
      use_last_modified true
      atomic_update true
    end


Running handlers:
[2015-10-30T05:04:28+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-10-30T05:04:28+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
[2015-10-30T05:04:28+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-10-30T05:04:28+00:00] ERROR: aws_s3_file[/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret] (appservers::sosconfig line 3) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: remote_file[/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/s3_file.rb line 36) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 400 "Bad Request"
[2015-10-30T05:04:28+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Stacktrace output:

```
Generated at 2015-10-30 05:04:28 +0000
Net::HTTPServerException: aws_s3_file[/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret] (appservers::appconfig line 3) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: remo
te_file[/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/s3_file.rb line 36) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 400 
"Bad Request"
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/http.rb:179:in `streaming_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/remote_file/http.rb:60:in `fetch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/remote_file/content.rb:71:in `grab_file_from_uri'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/remote_file/content.rb:56:in `try_multiple_sources'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/remote_file/content.rb:41:in `file_for_provider'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:40:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:462:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:339:in `do_generate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:150:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource.rb:585:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider.rb:363:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/resource.rb:585:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:648:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:648:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:687:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/client.rb:269:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:270:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:258:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:258:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:224:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:212:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:408:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:398:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:398:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:388:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:54:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:54:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You might want to consider asking or filing an issue on the aws cookbook: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/aws/issues.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @monkeymatrix please find my answer below. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there are some bugs in `aws_s3_file`. I wrote following recipe to solve this issue.

```
include_recipe 'aws'

require 'aws-sdk'

client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
bucket = client.get_object(bucket:'app-chefconfig', key: 'encrypted_data_bag_secret')

# Read content to variable
file_content = bucket.body.read 

# Log output (optional)
Chef::Log.info(file_content)

# Write content to file
file '/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  content file_content
  action :create
end
```